# Adding xml layout into my current Activity layout dynamically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i have an ArrayList of usernames for each username i want to add a xml layout (layout_one_user.xml) and put the username String into each TextView (name_user) present in the layout inflated.

my code in the main Activity is this:

```
    ll_counts = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_counts);
    lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LayoutInflater inflater_one_user = MainScreen.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout_one_user = inflater_one_user.inflate(R.layout.layout_one_user, null);

    TextView txt_counts     = (TextView)  layout_one_user.findViewById(R.id.name_user);
    ImageView delete_icon   = (ImageView) layout_one_user.findViewById(R.id.icon_delete);
    ImageView edit_icon = (ImageView) layout_one_user.findViewById(R.id.icon_edit);

for (int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++) {
    layout_one_user = new View(this);
    txt_counts.setText( usernames.get(i) );
    ll_counts.addView(layout_one_user);
    }
```

the layout_one_user is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:padding="5dp"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_edit"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon_delete"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="text" 
    />
```

and the layout in my main is:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_counts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't appear anything on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inflate your custom layout to `layout_one_user`:

```
View layout_one_user = inflater_one_user.inflate(R.layout.layout_one_user, null);
```

but then, on the very first iteration of your loop, you overwrite this variable with an empty `View`:

```
layout_one_user = new View(this);
```

Thus when you add `layout_one_user` to your layout, you're adding an "empty view" and you see no result.

It seems to me that you need to inflate a new layout for each user:

```
for (int i = 0; i < usernames.size(); i++) {
    View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_one_user, ll_counts, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView)  layout.findViewById(R.id.name_user);
    textView.setText(usernames.get(i));
    ll_counts.addView(layout);
}
```